# Jquery Files Conflict between slider and slick carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to install a jquery banner with a slick carousel. Problem is i am using two jquery files together, below is the code.

```
<!-- For slick carousel -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<!-- For  Slider -->
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

Both are conflicting with each other. Incase of both, slick doesnt work. 
How can i run slick carousel without any conflict?

Comment: have you tried jQuery.noConflict();  check this link https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: Try just using one? Most of the time it should work.

Comment: Not yet.. but i am checking posts for multiple options.

Comment: @alan0xd i have tried all the combinations but still no result

Comment: The slider and the carousel, what are they? Can you post links to them?

Comment: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/  - For the slider i got a package from a friend

Comment: just a stupid question but when you tried using one jquery library, did you include it above all your other scripts?  Also what is the version of the  jquery.min? you can see by looking in the top line of the file.  What is the slider you are using too

Comment: @Pete, i have already mentioned the conflicting jQuery files. Till now i have tried conflict function as well but still no solution. The mentioned JQuery Min is jQuery v1.7.1.

Comment: The problem is solved now.  Solution is very simple, use either both simple version or minified version.

Comment: I know you mentioned conflicting files, if you read my comment properly I asked if when you tried to only include one jquery library (as you should only ever need one as the new ones are backward compatible to a certain degree) was it above all your other js script includes, but if you've solved your problem then don't worry about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to add multiple jquery library files you just use latest jquery file and jquery migrate file, it will definitely help you..

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js